# How to log from FormEventSubscriber in Symfony 5.0?

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony5

I'm new in Symfony, and I'm trying to build my application. But I can't find in documentation how to use Logger in Event Subscriber for a form.

I have monolog.yml:

```
monolog:
    channels: ["my"]
    handlers:
        my_handler:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.project_dir%/log/%kernel.environment%.event.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["my"]
```

I have FormType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
//here some other fields are added
            ->addEventSubscriber(new FormEventSubscriber());
    }
```

Then, I have pretty dummy FormEventSubscriber:

```
class FormEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT   => 'onPreSubmit',
        ];
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    }
}
```

Now I must add LoggerInterface to it. I'm trying to insert this code to subscriber:

```
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $myLogger)
    {
        $this->logger = $myLogger;
    }
```

And then Symfony says that I must add argument to call addEventSubscriber(new FormEventSubscriber()) in FormType.

So how must I do it? When I simply make object of Logger() class in FormType and add it as argument, it logs nothing

Upd. I found the way, and it was obvious:) I just added constructor to FormType too, just like in subscriber:

```
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $myLogger)
    {
        $this->logger = $myLogger;
    }
```

and then called

```
->addEventSubscriber(new FormEventSubscriber($this->logger))
```

Comment: Inject the logger into your form type then pass it along to the subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

In your FormType instead of calling `new FormEventSubscriber()` you should inject the service, just like you do with the logger in the Subscriber. So your form's constructor should look something like:

```php
private $formEventSubscriber;

public function __construct(FormEventSubscriber $formEventSubscriber)
{
    $this->formEventSubscriber = $formEventSubscriber;
}
```

When you create your form in your controller using the form builder it will know to fetch the form from the container instead of manually creating it. This is usually done automatically through the `DependencyInjectionExtension` inside Symfony Form and usually does not require any additional configuration or changes on your part.

Comment: I'm not sure if injecting the subscriber into the type is the best approach.  The docs always show the subscriber being new-ed within the type.  If your form had multiple fields with the same form type then you would end up with the subscriber instance being shared.  Which may or may not be bad.  Not sure.  Or at least make the subscriber non-shared.

Comment: That is a fair warning, but I think it's fairly unlikely this will cause issues and I can't think of a use case for a stateful subscriber which needs to be "reset" between fields/usages.

Comment: There is the problem that FormEventSubscriber is not a service...